# Grab HTML source of web page after selecting tab with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I need to read the HTML of the page that appears when you go to, https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/ and select the "Non-Cashable GICs" tab.

The following code used to work but no longer does.
How can I read the HTML source of this tab?

```
library("RSelenium")

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "Tab_non-cashable")
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

remDr$close()
```

Comment: Hello, Why does'nt work? what error is throwing and in which line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click your `webElem`

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "Tab_non-cashable")
webElem$clickElement() # CLICK 

page <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

page %>%  
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(16)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  X1           X2                                     X3   
  <chr>        <chr>                                  <chr>
1 ""           "Non-registered and Registered (TFSA,~ Regi~
2 "14 months"  "Less than $10,000: 4.45%$10,000 to $~ 4.55%
3 "15 months*" "Less than $10,000: 0.25%\n$10,000 to~ 0.25%
4 "18 months"  "Less than $10,000: 4.50% \n\n$10,000~ 4.60%
```